# usb audio recording: clicking noice

Tags: windows, usb, audio, recording

I'm having problems recording audio on windows using usb audio devices. The recorded material will have some kind of jitter/clicking noice.

I tested three different usb microphones and three different recording applications. Every combination will have the same problem.

Does some one know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by applying this hot fix from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938136
It's a 64 bit Windows XP problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try, if possible, to connect only the usb device that you want to use as microphone and unplug the other usb devices.